# Having issues merging two dataframes using R (Extra rows?)

Tags: r

I am trying to merge two data sets using the `merge` function, one with 699 rows (`df1`) and 1 with 180 rows (`df2`) using a common column (`ID`) but I keep getting 187 rows (as opposed to 180 rows).

```
df_new <- merge(df1, df2, by="ID")
```

I have erased repeats from both df1 and from the new dataframe trying to find an answer but with both routes I keep getting 185 rows (which still is not 180).

```
newdf1 <- distinct(df1)

df_new_NR <- distinct(df_new)
```

I am just working with the smaller dataframe as that is what I need anyway but for learning's sake, how do I fix this please?

Comment: Does the ID column in df1 have duplicates? If so, how do we know which row from df1 should be merged with df2?

Comment: @ThomasRosa Thanks for the question, df1 has two duplicates which I have managed to identify using duplicates and removed using distinct or unique. It still left me with 5 more than expected. The rows should be merged based on having the same ID between the data frames.